# how to auto export files when merge a branch?

Tags: git

I'm working with a website using a git repository with 2 branches master-branch and dev-branch.

I work in a dev-branch and when things go fine I merge it with the master-branch. And then I need to copy the whole dir to the deployment directory or upload to the server.

I would like to know if there is any way to automatically export/copy those files/changes to another directory every time I merged/commit the master-branch?

---

I know there are some kind of nodejs plugin that watches a directory and auto upload files to the deployment server when some files inside changed. But I didn't try them.

I would appreciate if you have a better way to upload them without running a nodejs app, or using the git itself.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up a [`post-merge` hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) that does the task for you. However, this hook will always run when you do a `git merge` which might not be the best solution for general use.

I would set up a small script that does this for me.

First, you have to build the list of files that was modified. This can be done with [`git diff`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html):

```
git diff --name-only $FROMREV..$TOREV > filelist
```

Where

- `$FROMREV` is the old revision (i.e. the last revision where you created an archive)
- `$TOREV` is the new revision (i.e. the current state you want to export)
- `filelist` is the temporary file that will hold the file names to zip up later

This list of files could then use [`git archive`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-archive.html) to create an archive with the modified files:

```
git archive --format zip --output /full/path/to/archive.zip $TOREV $(cat filelist)
```

This instructs git to create a `zip` archive called `archive.zip` at directory `/full/path/to/`. The revision to be zipped up is `$TOREV`. In addition, not all files will be zipped but only those contained in `filelist`.

Or, as a one-liner:

```
git archive --format zip --output /full/path/to/archive.zip $TOREV $(git diff --name-only $FROMREV..$TOREV)
```

You would manually call this script whenever you think that something shall be exported and feed in `FROMREV`, `TOREV` and `/full/path/to/archive.zip`